# SQL - Is there an opposite but equivalent UNION function?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there an opposite but equivalent UNION function for mysql?

I know it's possible to do this with a longer query but I'm curious on whether or not there's a function equivalent.

I have 2 select statements for 2 different tables

```
select state, state_name, id, idname, phone, mobile, home from table1
select state, state_name, id, idname, phone, mobile, home from table2
```

And I need a query that pulls only from table1 and ONLY if idname, phone, mobile, home from table1 doesn't match with table2

For example: Table1 has

```
AK | Alaska | 1 | row6   | 453  | 567 | 123
```

but Table 2 has:

```
AK | Alaska | 1 | row6   | 453  | 567 | 123
AK | Alaska | 1 | row6   | NULL | 567 | 123
AK | Alaska | 1 | tttttt | 453  | 567 | 123
```

The query will display

```
AK | Alaska | 1 | row6   | NULL | 567 | 123
AK | Alaska | 1 | tttttt | 453  | 567 | 123
```

will NOT display

```
AK | Alaska | 1 | row6   | 453  | 567 | 123
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In standard SQL you can use the ANSI SQL `EXCEPT` operator which is an exact analogue of `UNION`

```
SELECT * FROM Table2
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

There is also an `INTERSECT` [set operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29) that would show rows that both sources have in common.

Unfortunately neither of these are supported in current versions of MySQL so you need to use one of these other 3 more verbose ways of achieving an anti semi join.

[NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Oracle, you'll use the [MINUS](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php) clause.

```
statement 1
MINUS
statement 2
```

or

```
statement 1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (statement 2)
```